# Passphrase requirement for old version of QT wallet

Tags: wallet, passphrase

I have an old wallet.dat file which was encrypted in October 2012. I don't have the exact passphrase but I have a rough idea. I was wondering if anyone knows how to get the passphrase requirement for this specific version (it would help with my guessing). I looked through the source code for Bitcoin-Qt version 0.7.0 and 0.7.1 but all I was able to find was this

> ui->warningLabel->setText(tr("Enter the new passphrase to the
>   wallet.
> Please use a passphrase of **10 or more random
>   characters**, or **eight or more words**."));

Which is line 33 of askpassphrasedialog.cpp file. I don't think this is a strict requirement for the passphrase although it helps. I would like to see the code which sets the passphrase requirement if possible. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

p.s. Does anyone know if it is possible to decrypt an old wallet without downloading the entire blockchain?

Answer (score 1):

I went through more files and it looks like only the guideline exists for the passphrase. The passphrase requirement of 10 or more random characters or eight or more words were not strictly enforced. Just in case other people were looking for the same information.